# Start powershell process and run a script

Tags: powershell

How do you pass flags into start-process powershell?

I would like to run powershell -file, however it is taken up as an argument to start-process.

Comment: do you mean you want it to get the set of cmds from the script/file instead of from the command-line?

Comment: I have a written script I would like to run instead of having to translate it into an array and maintain it.

Comment: so... "yes" then? ;) I'm trying to get you to improve the quality/clarity of your question... you'll note you already have 3 close votes...I'd also recommend adding some examples of the research you've done to try to solve this yourself (and why the results weren't successful (even better if you include the results you got))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just type in `Invoke-Item ("FilePath")` .  See [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176882.aspx) for more information.